# Does macOS offer a Scheduled Notifications Summary feature similar to iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, big-sur, monterey, sonoma

In iOS, there is a feature called "Scheduled Notifications Summary" that allows users to receive a summary of their notifications at specified times during the day. This is extremely useful for managing distractions and staying focused.

Is there a similar feature available in any version of macOS that enables scheduled summaries of notifications?

Comment: No, I don't think there's something like that.